# Calling Rest API by big size JSON Array

Tags: android, arrays, json, rest, api

I have an android app and I am working with sqlite. The task is, I am preparing over 200 records from sqlite as JSON array and  I am trying to call REST for sending it as String. Error is 414 URI too long.

What is the best practice?

Comment: do You make update by GET ?

Comment: Url queries are for specifying what data you want to GET/retrieve and how. Sending data is done in the body of a request, not in the url.

Comment: Yes I tried GET. Hi Tim I am new at REST. How can I send it on body. Is there any tutorial or link that you can share. It will be great. Thx

Comment: He seems to be a NOOB, do not worry get a hold on POST method, th data u send via url needs to be send in Post method in the body, GET does not have a body PUT and POST has

Comment: Thanks Niraj. I am new at Rest. Until now I always use SOAP but now I am in android development and I need to learn Rest. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

When you say it is to long then you send your record json file in the URL?!

When yes then use POST or PUT insted GET to send your records and put your record into body.

Not like:

```
GET /some_text/<your record file> HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com/
```

change to:

```
POST /some_text HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com/

<your record file>
```

or

```
PUT /some_text HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com/

<your record file>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will do it.

Comment: Small correction: a) pure REST has not methods, but state b) PUT/POST has functionality update/new record

Comment: a) yes you're right. I changed that. b) yes you're right. But at the end they do the same only the word is another to be able to better distinguish the functionality.